# Is there a way to invalidate NSBundle localization cache, withour restarting application? [iOS]

Tags: iphone, ios, private, localizable.strings

Let's assume that we can change in runtime Localizable.strings, that is placed in NSBundle
At the current moment, even if we change it's contents, *NSLocalizedString* would return old(cached) values.

1. Run Application
2. Get LocalizableString for specific key1 <- value1
3. Change Localizable.strings key1 = value2
4. <-- Do something in application to invalidate Localization cache -->
5. Check if LocalizableString for specific key1 == value2

What I've already tried:

- [[NSBundble mainBundle] invalidateResourceCache]
- [UIApplication _performMemoryWarning]
- Tried to see, if there's some dictionaries. used for caching, in ivars in NSBundle.
- Tried to see, in GNUStep implementation of NSBundle, but it's different from that we have in ios 6.0

What I cannot do (by definition):
 - I cannot swizzle [NSBundle localizableStringForKey:value:table]
 - I cannot change macroses
 - In general, I cannot affect Any Original Project code, only add something at step #4

This is only for development purposes only. So, I don't need to publish it in AppStore or something, so any private methods, or solutions are OK.

So, the question is. May be someone know the way to do it, or someone who give me another ideas how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: "Let's assume that we can change in runtime Localizable.strings" - you can't.

Comment: Well, I can do it, when running application on simulator.

Comment: On the simulator, the apps run with your user account's permission and they're not restricted to be run in a sandbox. On the device, you cannot modify files located in the app bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NOTE: This solution uses private APIs and your app submissions to the App Store will be rejected if you use this code.

So, after some search I've found link that helped me

[How to remove NSBundle cache](http://michelf.ca/blog/2010/killer-private-eraser/)

```
// First, we declare the function. Making it weak-linked 
// ensures the preference pane won't crash if the function 
// is removed from in a future version of Mac OS X.
extern void _CFBundleFlushBundleCaches(CFBundleRef bundle) 
  __attribute__((weak_import));

BOOL FlushBundleCache(NSBundle *prefBundle) {
    // Before calling the function, we need to check if it exists
    // since it was weak-linked.
    if (_CFBundleFlushBundleCaches != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Flushing bundle cache with _CFBundleFlushBundleCaches");
        CFBundleRef cfBundle =
           CFBundleCreate(nil, (CFURLRef)[prefBundle bundleURL]);
        _CFBundleFlushBundleCaches(cfBundle);
        CFRelease(cfBundle);
        return YES; // Success
    }
    return NO; // Not available
}
```

After flushing bundle cache, new localizations keys are used.
So now I don't need to restart my application in simulator in order to see changes in localizable strings.

Comment: As this is private API usage, you will not be able to submit apps using this workaround. I just tried - and failed.

Comment: As was mentioned in the question itself:  This is only for development purposes only. So, I don't need to publish it in AppStore or something, so any private methods, or solutions are OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **uncache** solution.

use `Localizable.nocache.strings` in your `lproj` folders.

e.g. `example.bundle/Resources/de.lproj/Localizable.nocache.strings`

loading localized strings after getting `url` via FileManager.

```
func localizedString(key: String) -> String {
   let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleUrl)
   return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "Localizable.nocache")
}
```