# Different values from `localizedString`

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-cloud-firestore, foundation

I want to implement dynamic localization inside my app. I use Firestore to store json. Also, I want to be able to manually select language inside my app.

To do that, I use `Bundle` with path for specific lang like this:

```
let innerPath = internalCustomBundle.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj")
let innerBundle = Bundle(path: innerPath)!
```

The problem is, that if I use `internalCustomBundle`, then I have up-to-date string synced with server. But at the same, `innerBundle` always return an old one, firstly initializated remote string.

So the steps looks like this:

1. Launch the app.
2. `localizedString` from internalCustomBundle and innerBundle are the same.
3. Go to server and update the string.
4. String from `internalCustomBundle` up-to-date new string, innerBundle old string. (I have `addSnapshotListener` to listen for updates).

General bundle (internalCustomBundle):

```
NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/27E2BF13-B415-46D3-ADD8-0DE9A7F0D9E2/Documents/DynamicLocalization> (not yet loaded)
```

Language specific bundle (innerBundle):

```
NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/27E2BF13-B415-46D3-ADD8-0DE9A7F0D9E2/Documents/DynamicLocalization/en.lproj> (not yet loaded)
```

Is it an Apple bug? By the way, I only have `en`.

Write to bundle method:

```
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bundlePath.path) {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(
                at: bundlePath,
                withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                attributes: [:]
            )
        }
        let languages = json.dictionaryValue
        for language in languages.keys {
            let langPath = bundlePath.appendingPathComponent("\(language).lproj", isDirectory: true)
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: langPath.path) {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(
                    at: langPath,
                    withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                    attributes: [:]
                )
            }
            let sentences = json[language].dictionaryValue.reduce("", {
                $0 + "\"\($1.key)\" = \"\($1.value.stringValue)\";\n"
            })
            let filePath = langPath.appendingPathComponent("Localizable.strings")
            let data = sentences.data(using: .utf32)
            
            fileManager.createFile(
                atPath: filePath.path,
                contents: data,
                attributes: [:]
            )
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681626/how-to-invalidate-cache-from-nsbundle-in-swift/46989111

Comment: nosync did the trick for me